# Qt configure freetype error

Tags: qt, configure

I am trying to build a QT for ARM cortex-8 board.

I successfully installed Host configuration as per the given instruction: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_for_Embedded_Linux

at the time of ARM board target build configuration, i have created my own mkspec file
linux-TIarmv7-g++ which has configuration as below:

```
> #
> # qmake configuration for building with arm-linux-g++
> #
> 
> include(../../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
> include(../../common/g++-unix.conf) include(../../common/linux.conf)
> include(../../common/qws.conf)
> 
> # modifications to g++.conf
> #Toolchain
> 
> 
> #Compiler Flags to take advantage of the ARM architecture QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon
> -mfloat-abi=softfp QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp QMAKE_CC                = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc QMAKE_CXX               = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ QMAKE_LINK              =
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        =
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
> 
> # modifications to linux.conf QMAKE_AR = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs QMAKE_OBJCOPY = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy QMAKE_STRIP =
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip
> 
> QMAKE_INCDIR += $$TSLIB_INCDIR QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$TSLIB_LIBDIR
> QMAKE_LIBS   += -lts
> 
> load(qt_config)
```

I have already installed codesourcery toolchain, my environment is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit operating system and target board is ARM-cortex8

My configuration is like below:

./configure -prefix /usr/local/qt-embedded -embedded arm -platform qws/linux-x86_64-g++ -xplatform qws/linux-TIarmv7-g++ -depths 16,24,32 -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-glib -no-cups -no-largefile -no-accessibility -no-openssl -no-gtkstyle -qt-mouse-pc -qt-mouse-linuxtp -qt-mouse-linuxinput -plugin-mouse-linuxtp -plugin-mouse-pc -fast -confirm-license -v

After execution and verbose i get below errors: related to freetype libraries

```
> m-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lts collect2: ld returned 1
> exit status make: *** [sound] Error 1 sound disabled. FreeType
> auto-detection... () arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O3
> -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wall -W  -I../../../mkspecs/qws/linux-TIarmv7-g++ -I. -o freetype.o freetype.cpp freetype.cpp:42:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file
> or directory compilation terminated. make: *** [freetype.o] Error 1
> FreeType disabled. Determining machine byte-order...
> (/home/rootx/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/mkspecs/qws/linux-TIarmv7-g++
> yes /home/rootx/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1
> /home/rootx/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1)
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o endiantest endiantest.o     -lts
> /home/rootx/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:
> cannot find -lts collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: ***
> [endiantest] Error 1 Unknown byte order!
> 
> The target system byte order could not be detected!
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like freetype development libraries are not installed.

Does sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev solve your problem?

Comment: Ok hold on, two things: it looks like you are running make -j4 or something to that effect. Can you just run make without threads? That way we double check for sure that that's the line where things fail and not earlier or later. Also, can you do "updatedb && locate 'ft2build.h' so we find out where ft2build.h is and if it's in the include path?

Comment: I simply gave 'make' command. after file locating i get below message:/home/rootx/freetype-2.4.9/devel/ft2build.h
/home/rootx/freetype-2.4.9/include/ft2build.h
/home/rootx/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/src/3rdparty/freetype/devel/ft2build.h
/home/rootx/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/src/3rdparty/freetype/include/ft2build.h
/usr/include/ft2build.h

Comment: Ok, that doesn't seem like it's a problem. Sorry, this is getting very hard without sitting by your side.